# java nio FileLock.release() throws ClosedChannelException and truncates my file

Tags: java, nio, truncate, file-locking

I've got e:\myfile.txt with some random contents:

```
abcabcxyz...abc
```

Then I try to use nio `FileLock` like below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
public class FileLockTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileLock lock = null;
        try(FileChannel ch=new FileOutputStream(args[0]).getChannel())
        {
            lock=ch.lock();//No param exclusive lock.
            //lock(0L,ch.size(),true) for shared lock.
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(lock!=null){
                try{
                    lock.release();//throws exception!
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon running it and I got:

```
PS> java FileLockTest e:\myfile.txt
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl.release(Unknown Source)
        at FileLockTest.main(FileLockTest.java:17)
```

I open myfile.txt again, all contents are missing, seems
`FileLock` has truncated it, really strange to me.

Could you help to explain what goes wrong here?

Comment: Creating the FileOutputStream has truncated your file, not the lock

Comment: As you are using try-with-resources the channel is closed *before* the finally block executes. So the lock is not valid when you try to release it.

Comment: Depending what you want to do with the lock, you could use `try (FileChannel ch=new FileOutputStream("foo").getChannel(); FileLock lock = ch.lock())` as the FileLock is AutoClosable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content is missing because you've opened your file with an output stream without using 'append' mode, which erases all the previous content before performing any writing operation.

If you need to keep the existing content and add new information within your file, then you need to open it in 'append' mode, by passing a second boolean parameter with value `true`.

```
FileChannel ch = new FileOutputStream(args[0], true)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean)

Also, as already said in the comments, what is giving you the `ClosedChannelException` is the fact that `FileLock` is bound to a file channel which has been already closed once you've exited the `try` block of your `try-with` statement. In fact, once you've reached your `finally` block the channel has been closed already, and any attempt to release a lock on a closed channel will fail.

So to answer your question, it's not the lock which erases your data, but rather the way how you access your file. Besides, since both `FileOutputStream` and `FileLock` implement `AutoClosable`, you could include both of them in the `try-with` statement and rewrite your code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (FileChannel ch = new FileOutputStream(args[0], true).getChannel();
         FileLock lock = ch.lock()) {

        //do your operations....

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```